# Default method in Jackson MixIn interface doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, mixins

I'm using a bean of which I don't control the source, say: `TheirClass`:

```
public class TheirClass {

    private String property;
}
```

I want to a timestamp to every `TheirClass` instance I serialize using a `MixIn`:

```
public interface TheirClassMixIn {

    @JsonProperty
    default long getTimestamp() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

and I let Spring know about it:

```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer someCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder
                .mixIn(TheirClass.class, TheirClassMixIn.class);
    }
```

but this doesn't seem to work. What am I missing and how can I achieve putting a fixed extra property to every `TheirClass` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this just by adding property to mix-in class/interface because ["Mix-in" annotations are a way to associate annotations with classes, without modifying (target) classes themselves, originally intended to help support 3rd party datatypes where user can not modify sources to add annotations.](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

You can use it by adding `@JsonAppend` to your mix-in interface, this annotation is **used to add virtual properties to an object in addition to regular ones when that object is serialized.**

It can be used with the mix-in functionality to avoid modifying the original POJO.

Let’s rewrite your example:

```java
@JsonAppend(
    props = {
            @JsonAppend.Prop(
                    name = "timestamp", type = Long.class,
                    value = TimestampPropertyWriter.class
            )
    }
)
public interface TheirClassMixIn {}
```

To complete this story I’ll show an implementation of `TimestampPropertyWriter`. It’s just a class that knows how to evaluate the value of our “virtual” property given an instance of `TheirClass`:

```java
public class TimestampPropertyWriter extends VirtualBeanPropertyWriter {

    public TimestampPropertyWriter() {
    }

    public TimestampPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyDefinition propDef,
                                   Annotations contextAnnotations,
                                   JavaType declaredType) {
        super(propDef, contextAnnotations, declaredType);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object value(Object bean,
                           JsonGenerator gen,
                           SerializerProvider prov) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public VirtualBeanPropertyWriter withConfig(MapperConfig<?> config,
                                                AnnotatedClass declaringClass,
                                                BeanPropertyDefinition propDef,
                                                JavaType type) {
        return new TimestampPropertyWriter(propDef, declaringClass.getAnnotations(), type);
    }
}
```